css ::after element height not works
I have a Next.js app with five buttons that have the same SCSS class and height. However, the height of the ::after element in one button is different and I don't know why.
Scss class:
.underline-button {
color: $color;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;

&:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: $color;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

&:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

&:active:after {
  width: 0;
}

}
Jsx code:
export default function Home() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
    <div className="underline-button">Button</div>
  </div>
);

Render output
(https://i.sstatic.net/9nDgBtcK.png)

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Your image appears to show two of the underlines being thicker than the other 3 - could you clarify why you see only one? At 1px height you may be seeing just the 'rounding error' created when the system has to map one CSS pixel to the several screen pixels on modern screens Try zooming in and out - do the lines that are thicker change?

It seems that you have written your code in wrong hierarchy.



$color: #333;

.underline-button {
  color: $color;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 24px;

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: $color;
    transition: width 0.3s;
  }

  &:hover {
    &:after {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  &:active {
    :after {
      width: 0;
    }
  }
}
<div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
  <div class="underline-button">Button</div>
</div>



As your code is in .SCSS please check this.

Could you clarify what is meant by 'wrong hierarchy' and in what way that influences the height of the lines?

I have just run the fiddle you provided and find that as I alter the zoom levels then different lines appear thicker (see my comment above). This doesn't seem to have anything to do with hierarchy.

@AHaworth what I meant is that &:active:after should be in brackets.
